# Powershell cannot open Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell

I am a beginner trying to learn Python using Learn Python the Hard Way. My computer is running on Windows 10, and I am using ActivePython 2.7.13. I have tried various other options, including setting the Path, but obtained no results. It gave me：

```
ActivePython 2.7.13.2715 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.13 (default, May 16 2017, 03:06:05) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on    win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

If I try to run a simple .py file with print, it appears to not do anything:

```
PS C:\Users\lisan\mystuff> python test.py
PS C:\Users\lisan\mystuff>
```

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think you can't open Python?  Your first block of output clearly came from Python.  Also, your second output example doesn't show any errors, so your python script _did_ execute; it just didn't _print_ anything.  Perhaps if you edited your question to show us the contents of `test.py`, we could explain why that happened.

Comment: @JohnGordon I did not realize that "opening" python means interacting with it in powershell rather than opening a new window with ps, and I did not realize that you need to save before the text can show up with ps...thanks a lot for coping with my ignorance!

Comment: @LisaLan, you're not interacting with Python in PowerShell. The shell is simply waiting for Python to exit. If it didn't wait, then it would compete with Python for access to the console, which would be a confusing mess. The console window isn't owned by either PowerShell or Python. They're both attached to it as clients of the console host process, which in Windows 7+ is conhost.exe.